# What does for i = 1: ... mean in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

note that the code below is obtained from Matlab documentation except for the bottom portion.

```
function B = nway(A,n)
% Compute average of every N elements of A and put them in B.

if ((mod(numel(A),n) == 0) && (n>=1 && n<=numel(A)))

B = ones(1,numel(A)/n);
    k = 1;   

    for i = 1 : numel(A)/n
         B(i) = mean(A(k + (0:n-1)));
         k = k + n;

    end
```

What does the for loop code mean, especially the following line?

```
for i = 1 : numel(A)/n
```

and how does the `i` work by inserting it in `B(i)`?

Comment: I think you're missing the point of Matlab if you haven't tried entering expressions such as `1:5`, `1:sqrt(81)`, `10:-1:2`, `12:numel(A)` *etc* at the command line and started to figure out the answer to your own question.  Once you've figured that out, start experimenting with `for i = 1:12` and more complicated expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A for-loop in Matlab is constructed as

```
for iterationVariable = listOfValues
    do something
end
```

The `iterationVariable` will take on the value of the first column of `listOfValues` in the first iteration of the loop, then the value of the second column, etc. You can then use `iterationValue` in your calculations.

```
for i=1:numel(A)/n
```

will therefore set the value of `i` to `1,2,3...` up to the value of `"number of elements of A divided by n"`.

```
B(i)
```

is an indexing operation, that returns the `i`th element of the array `B`.

As @HighPerformanceMark suggests, I very much recommend trying out these expressions at the command line, or to work through the "getting started" section of the excellent Matlab documentation.